# Can't get Metadata Publishing for my WCF webHttpBinding Service

Tags: wcf

I keep getting the page when I browse to my svc file that metadata publishing is not turned on but I have done everything for it. Here's my web.config. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AlphaFrontEndSiteASP.TestsServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="AlphaFrontEndSiteASP.Services.TestsService">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="AlphaFrontEndSiteASP.Services.TestsService" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior"> 
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="AlphaFrontEndSiteASP.TestsServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="AlphaFrontEndSiteASP.Services.TestsService" />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I don't think REST services expose metadata - that's a SOAP concept.

Comment: How do I call the service or use in Telerik control that expects metadata?